# No one wins in my Naughts and Crosses game

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const char PLAYER_1 = 'O';
const char PLAYER_2 = 'X';


int row = 0;
int col = 0;

int winningStates[8][3][2] = {{{0,0},{0,1},{0,2}},{{1,0},{1,1},{1,2}},{{2,0},{2,1},{2,2}},{{3,0},{3,1},{3,2}},
                                {{4,0},{4,1},{4,2}},{{5,0},{5,1},{5,2}},{{6,0},{6,1},{6,2}},{{7,0},{7,1},{7,2}}};

//This sets all the elements within the body to '-' to indicate that the square is free
void intialise(char board[][3])
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int a=0;a<=3;a++)
        {
            board[i][a] = '-';

        }
    }


}

//This displays the board on the screen
void display(char board[][3])
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int a=0;a<3;a++)
        {
            cout << board[i][a] << "\t ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//setValue() sets the cell indicated by the parameter to the value that is contained within the symbol parameter
void setValue(int row, int col, char symbol, char board[][3])
{
    board[row][col] = symbol;
}

//isFree() returns true if the cell identified by the parameter contains '-'
bool isFree(int row, int col, char board[][3])
{
    if(board[row][col]=='-')
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }
}

bool hasWon(char symbol,char board[][3])
{
    bool match = false;

    row = 0;
    col = 0;

    for(int m=0;m<8;m++)
    {
        for(int s=0;s<3;s++)
        {
            row = winningStates[m][s][0];
            col = winningStates[m][s][1];

            if(board[row][col]==symbol)
            {
                match = true;
            }
            else
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return match;
    //return false;
}

int main()
{
    char board[3][3];

    srand(time(0));

    bool gameOver = false;

    char player = PLAYER_1;

    int count = 0;

    intialise(board);
   // display();

    while(gameOver!=true)
    {     

        do
        {
            row = rand()%3;
            col = rand()%3;
        }
        while(! isFree(row,col,board));


        setValue(row,col,player,board);
        if(player==PLAYER_1)
        {
            player = PLAYER_2;
        }
        else
        {
            player = PLAYER_1;
        }

        gameOver = hasWon(player,board);

        if(gameOver==true)
        {
            cout << "WON" << endl;
        }
        count++;

        if(count==9)
        {
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        }


        display(board);
        cout << endl;


    }
}
```

In this code, I never get "WON" message. And, one cell is always free, without any symbol.
It doesn't matter how many times I run this code, No one wins!! Why is this? Please help!!

Comment: The logic in `hasWon()` is wrong.

Comment: Now would be a good time to start learning how to debug.

Comment: I don't recommend using loops that are potentially infinitely long because you only break out of it when you've picked something randomly. In this case, it's *unlikely* to matter, but I suggest getting out of the habit. Keep track of how many free cells there are and pick one from those. No need to loop.

Comment: @PaulR: Hi, yeah, but I have Netbeans with cygwin. Seems like it is not good for C++ debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a logic error, try this

```
bool hasWon(char symbol,char board[][3])
{
    for(int m=0;m<8;m++)
    {
        bool found_line = true;
        for(int s=0;s<3;s++)
        {
            int row = winningStates[m][s][0];
            int col = winningStates[m][s][1];

            if(board[row][col]!=symbol)
            {
                found_line = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found_line)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think it helps to choose better variable names for this kind of task, `match` is not very good because it doesn't say what you are matching. Which seems to have been your error.

Comment: Cool..Thanks a lot John :). I really appreciate it. +1 from me :)